# If the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are coplanar, then find the following determinant

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

If the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are coplanar, then find \begin{vmatrix} \vec{a} & \vec{b} & \vec{c} \\ \vec{a}\cdot\vec{a} & \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} & \vec{a}\cdot\vec{c} \\\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a} & \vec{b}\cdot\vec{b} & \vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}\\ \end{vmatrix}

I am not able to understand how to proceed to solve this determinant as it has dot products. Any idea on how to proceed? The answer is given as $0$.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried computing the determinant in the regular way to see what you get?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble seeing just what your determinant symbol means, exactly.  Clearly the second and third row entries are all *numbers*, so that makes sense.  But how do we interpret the first row?  The entries are *vectors*, how is this then a $3 \times 3$ determinant?  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are coplanar. This means there exists scalars $x,y,z$ (**not all zero**) such that
$$x\vec{a}+y \vec{b}+z \vec{c}=\vec{0}.$$
Now 
$$(x\vec{a}+y \vec{b}+z \vec{c}) \cdot \vec{a}=\vec{0} \cdot \vec{a}=0$$
This gives
$$x (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a})+y (\vec{b}\cdot \vec{a})+z (\vec{c}\cdot \vec{a})=0$$
Likewise
$$x (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})+y (\vec{b}\cdot \vec{b})+z (\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b})=0$$

Now you have the following homogeneous system of equations in $x,y,z$ such that it has **non-zero** solution. 
\begin{align*}
x\vec{a}+y \vec{b}+z \vec{c} & =\vec{0}\\
x (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a})+y (\vec{b}\cdot \vec{a})+z (\vec{c}\cdot \vec{a}) & =0\\
x (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})+y (\vec{b}\cdot \vec{b})+z (\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b})&=0.
\end{align*}

Now think about determinants.

Comment: Wow... I had no idea that the determinant could be interpreted this way! Otherwise if one tries solve by direct method, it becomes too long and cumbersome... Thanks...